# Random number always 0

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that generates a number and i'm pushing it into my array, but the number generated is always 0, why  ?

```js
function generateId()
{
    var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*10) + 1); 

    if(randomNum = ids.indexOf(randomNum)) 
    {
        return generateId();
    };

    ids.push[randomNum];

    return randomNum;
};
```

Comment: Should be `if(randomNum == ids.indexOf(randomNum))`

Comment: I don't understand what that line is supposed to do anyway. If the random number is found in the array and the position of that number is the same as the number ?? Should it be `ids.indexOf(randomNum) === -1` (or `!== -1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note there is an error in your code. You are using assignment operator `=` in your `if` condition whereas you should be using equality operator `==`. Also, you are using `ids.push[randomNumber]` while you should be using `ids.push( randomNumber )`. Below is a working function and code snippet:

```
function generateId()
{
    if( ids.length >= 10 )
    {
      alert("max length reached.");
      console.log( ids );
      return ids;
    }
    else
    {
      var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*10) + 1);   
      if( ids.indexOf(randomNum) > -1 ) 
      {
          return generateId();
      }
      else
      {
        ids.push(randomNum);
        console.log( ids );
      }
    }
};
```

```js
var ids = [];

function generateId()
{
    if( ids.length >= 10 )
    {
      alert("max length reached.");
      console.log( ids );
      return ids;
    }
    else
    {
      var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*10) + 1);   
      if( ids.indexOf(randomNum) > -1 ) 
      {
          return generateId();
      }
      else
      {
        ids.push(randomNum);
        console.log( ids );
      }
    }
};
```

```html
<button id="generate" onclick="generateId()">Generate Id</button>
```

Comment: I fixed my error Mohit, i am trying now to search in the array if the number generated exists, if exists, should generate another number and then add it to array, it should be a recursive function. thank you for your reply tho :).

Comment: @GoddamnRooT Thanks. But there is already a check for that in your code snippet, which I have included in my solution also. Did you try this code?